# MSAccess 2007 changing connection properties in form

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I would like some help in creating a form with-in an MS Access front end to select a database/database server for the access backend.

A little history first;

I created a MSAccess 2007 acccdp database, it was designed as a single user to be run locally. (For a university research project with little or no funds for this).

Eventually there was a need to expand the database to be used by several people at once in the same office so what i did;

Install SQLExpress 2008r2 on a desktop. 
Used Database Tools > Move Data > Sql Sever to migrate the tables to the new SQL server.

Now I want to create a second test database for development/training etc... Also, I need to adjust the properties for a different database sever (at home).

So I figure I need a form to auto exec (rather than the switchboard) which will allow you to select the database server and Database to join the linked tables to, then if successfully connects to open the switchboard.

I can create the form, but i need help with the vba to adjust the database connection properties.

I am just trying to help this project and am not a programmer in any way.

Thanks in advance

Roger

Comment: A start: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Link_All_SQL_Server_Tables

Comment: Thanks, a good place to start, will investigate.

Comment: Do you need to have a dsn for each connection or is that what the connection propertiues are for?

Comment: The connection property is the same for each table, and does not have to have a DSN, you can get connection strings from http://connectionstrings.com or you can manually link a table from your server and check the connection property to get a string for use in your code.

Comment: Thanks, last night i got an sql server connection string working. I am on the way. Just working on a way to integrate it into a module to dynamically change it rather than push button as it looks a little clumsy. The server and database names to be held in a table at the front end side.

Answer (score 0):

If your choice is between two connections, you can check if the existing connection is working and if not, switch to the second. However, a button may still be the best bet. This snippet works for me, but it sets the connection timeout to just a second, so the server may be available if you had only waited a little longer, and even with this time out, there is enough of a delay for an impatient person to start clicking.

```
Function IsSQLServer() As String
''Reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library
Dim cn As New adodb.Connection

    ''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676718(v=vs.85).aspx
    ''Provider=sqloledb
    cn.ConnectionString = ServerCon & "Connect Timeout=1;"

    On Error Resume Next
    cn.Open

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        IsSQLServer = "No;" & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        If cn.State = adStateOpen Then
            IsSQLServer = "Yes"
        Else
            IsSQLServer = "Maybe"
        End If
        cn.Close
    End If

    Set cn = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - looks great. But they will be using over VPN and knowing the 'err'  quality of the connect, a time out of 2mis might be more appropriate. But definately a thought to work in.

Comment: What I was looking at really is to Create 3 named connections; eg; 'Production' & 'Development' & 'Test' - each with defined parameters 'server' & 'databasename'. This should be toggled thru a form.  Button would be easiest, but why make life easy ;)..  The quest is how to set up the variables to be entered and recalled in the module.  This i have not  done yet, a skill i must learn.

Comment: You have a database, a table is a great place to store stuff :) I generally keep a small table in both the back-end and front-end to hold various bits and pieces I need for the next time. As an aside, I also keep a table of tables in the front-end, it is surprisingly useful.

Comment: Sorry, my typing went awry the second time (after a timeout), I meant to keep the connections in a front end table. Currently the only front end table i keep is the switchboard, plus I would add the connection properties.  What do you use a table of tables for - front end versioning?  Do you know ( i will google as well) any illustrative examples of using a database connection with modules and variables? (Maybe just the use of modules and variables?)  Thanks again